# Create table in MS ACCESS 2010 - Using Oracle SQL query

Tags: ms-access

We have standard SQL Query's which we run everyday to get information from oracle database tables. these are having joins and linked to more than 1 tables in database. using sql developer we run these and get data and export to excel.

My question is, can we create table in MS ACCESS 2010 - (Using ODBC connection) - Using these standard SQL queries? could you please let me know how to do this?

like how we do in Orale.

like...

create table tablename as select * from XXXXX;

In excel after connection to ODBC there is a box where we could paste standard query but i am not able to find that in MS ACCESS. kindly help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Access 2010 go to the **external data** tab and select **odbc database** and select the odbc you set up to the SQL database.  You will then be able to link to the tables in Access.

This will let you view the SQL tables in Access.  You can then create your own queries/forms/reports to view the data the way you like.

Comment: Yes, but that tab will show all tables which are in Oracle database. My question is - is there any way to paste the query which is validated (current i have the code which is created using some of those tables) to get result?

Comment: If you have SQL to paste into a query then yes, all you would need to do is create a query, switch to the SQL view of the query, paste your SQL and it should work.

Comment: Thanks, I did it, but how that query will link to Oracle database - I means how to connect - where to enter login details?

Comment: You can take care of all the login details in the ODBC object you create to link to the SQL database so you need not log in all the while.  You need to link to the SQL tables in External Data -> ODBC Databases and they will appear in your list of tables

Answer (score 0):

You can combine ODBC pass-through query and make table query

- create pass through query 'pq' of Oracle SQL like "select sysdate from dual"
- create make table query 'mq' like "SELECT * INTO new_table FROM pq;"

```
'optional: skip ODBC credential
Dim qd As DAO.QueryDef
Set qd = Access.CurrentDb.QueryDefs("pq")
qd.Connect = "ODBC;DSN=datasetname;UID=user;PWD=pass"
'run make table query
DoCmd.OpenQuery mq, , acReadOnly
```

Similar topic below
[Append Records From Passthrough Query to Local Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10215212/append-records-from-passthrough-query-to-local-table)