# Way to reference access and sql server tables without directly referring to connection string within query

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, vba

I am working on a project that will use MS Access as front end and SQL Server for data storage. I don't want to link the tables directly because I don't want to take the speed hit to the front end from the 'live' updates. I can't reference the Access DB through JET etc because it is not based in a fixed location so I can't pass through and run directly from server end

I've got as far as this (vba in access):

```
Sub inserttoaccess()
   strSQL = "insert into AccessTable SELECT * FROM [myserverconnectionstring;].servertable"
   CurrentDb.Execute (strSQL), dbFailOnError
End Sub    

Sub inserttoserver()
    strSQL = "insert into [myserverconnectionstring;].servertable SELECT * FROM AccessTable"
    CurrentDb.Execute (strSQL), dbFailOnError
End Sub
```

Which works, and hopefully demonstrates what I need to do, but I'm looking for a way to do it which doesn't require me to keep referring back to the connection in every query. Maybe a way to link to the server without linking specific tables or a function that I could hardcode the connection string but pass the query, but not sure how that would work...

This is the first time I've been looking at using MS Access and SQL Server together so looking for some input as to how those more experienced approach this please

Comment: Make your life easier and remove the MS Access part. The direct call to SQL is going to take .0001 seconds.

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to make things too hard on yourself. Linked tables to SQL Server work well. Because the links hold the connection string, your code and queries don't have to reference it. You can also link queries to SQL Server, which is a handy way to call functions and stored procedures.

Comment: @Chuck The MS Access part for is the eventual users to enter their data so that I can quickly set up an environment with buttons, data validation, errorcatching etc

Comment: @kismert So standard practice would be to link the tables and use forms etc to populate the tables in access 'in bulk' rather than allow the user direct access? Effectively removing the need for the connection string by duplicating the data on an access table that can be directly referenced, is this correct? Is this typically much slower? how about size restrictions?

Comment: I've had a lot of success with MS Access ADP (Access data projects) though for some unknown reason they are possibly becoming discontinued. An ADP is basically native access to SQL Server from within MS Access - try it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly (for some) ADPs are out. ADO is out too.

The current recommendation for Access/SQL Server desktop applications is linked tables and queries over DAO using the SQL Server Native Client, version 11.0 or later. Starting with Access 2013, Microsoft has done a lot of work to make this arrangement perform well with SQL Server and Azure.

As for your question in the comments, whether you need to synchronize local Access tables with remote SQL ones depends on what the application is supposed to do:

- If the user expects to be able to work while disconnected from the
  network/internet/cloud, then you need to synchronize local tables
- But, if you are doing a standard application, where persistent links
  to the SQL data are assumed, then just do all of your reads and
  writes against linked SQL tables. Use pass-through queries to call stored procedures and functions.

Comment: I believe ADP's are meant to be replaced by some kind of sharepoint implementation but **they are so useful**

Comment: @kismert. Still can't upvote but I have accepted this as the answer, whilst it may not be the approach I will use (and only because I am more comfortable hiding connections from users in code rather than just hiding tables I don't want them messing with), it does seem to be the standard solution and does avoid any coded connection strings repetition. Thanks for your time helping with this

Answer (score 1):

[This Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10215212/append-records-from-passthrough-query-to-local-table), answered by HansUp (Sorry not enough rep for an upvote) 
specifically this:

```
INSERT INTO MyNewTable (fld1, fld2)
SELECT first_field, second_field FROM YourPassThruQuery;
```

provides a possible solution without linked tables

Rather than the approach I was trying to take of inserting to an access table from a sqlserver table I can insert to an access table from an access pass through query

By having the connection string in a couple of pass through queries that relate to all the data I need from the server I can then reference these in the multitude of sub queries relating to user input without having the connection string in each one

The question of whether this is method that **should** be used for this problem stands, but this seems like a viable solution, or at least compromise to limit the number of connection references

**Edit:** By combining the above with [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/112108) and hardcoding the connection string I should be able to only reference the connection once, provided the SQL server tables are all on the same database

Comment: It seems to me that you are only moving the problem around. True, you avoid linked tables, but instead you use linked pass-through queries, which is essentially the same thing. You could avoid all static links by dynamically linking in code, but you would have to do all of your SQL work in code only, and you couldn't use any stand-alone tables or queries at all.

Comment: @kismert The benefit of this for me is that it isn't two way. Linked tables means change in access table = change in sql server table, whereas this is just going to be a read only version of what may be a full or portion of a table. Most of the smaller queries that I didn't want to have to keep putting the connection string into will be handled through code anyway because they'll contain variables based on user selections in forms

Comment: If you don't want to allow your Access users to modify data in a linked SQL Server table, either manage their permissions in SQL Server (revoke `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, and `DELETE` privileges) or link the table with a separate SQL Server read-only account.

Comment: @Hansup the link is set up through a generic account, this account does have those privileges because I do want to be able to perform these actions from this account through the access db. However I want to be able to do them through forms/vba without having a version of the table on the access front end that users can directly perform those actions against. I.e. I don't want users to be able to circumvent any front end data validation and affect the table directly themselves. Thanks for your help via the post quoted above by the way